# MATLAB: create a function 1 x N that can accept array of logical or double

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have to create this first script that can later be used by different `1 x N`  arrays. How would I code a `1 x N` array function so in later use can include elements  either 1 or 0 (logical or double).

As an example :

```
V = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1];
```

So I can later test out code for many different values and lengths of V.

TEST CASE 1-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

> > [V] = lab3p2partA([1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0])

V =

1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0

Comment: You mean a random array?

Comment: Your desired input and output make absolutely no sense.  What is the relationship between them?  We can see that the function accepts an array of `logical` or `double`.... but **what is it supposed to do with the array**?

Comment: perform various tasks on a 1 x n array, V, whose elements are either 1 or 0

Comment: Again, it doesn't make any sense. How does `in --> [1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0]` produce `out -> [1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]`??????

Comment: That was an example of a later script I would create.The function should use a for loop to flip every third entry
of V (i.e. make the entry 0 if it is 1 or make it 1 if it is 0). This loop should modify V directly.

Comment: So if there's more than one rule to modify `V`, make that clear.  Again, I have no idea what it is you want.  I'm afraid I'm going to have to vote to close your question if you keep avoiding what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `V` is already given, simply do:

```
V = V == 1;
```

... to turn `V` into a `logical` array.

However, if your intent is to generate a random array, you can use [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) to generate a random integer array:

```
V = randi(2, N, 1) - 1;
```

You generate numbers of 1 or 2, then subtract by 1.  `randi`'s minimum value to generate is 1 and not 0 unfortunately.

You can also use [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html)  with thresholding as the other post suggests:

```
V = rand(N, 1) > 0.5;
```

Make sure you choose 0.5 because `rand` generates things uniformly.  `rand` generates values from `[0,1]` uniformly, so if you want (on average) an even number of 0s and 1s, set your threshold to 0.5.

Comment: Would V = V ==1;   allow me to write a function with any input variable V?

Comment: That syntax simply converts `V` to logical.  I have no idea what it is you want with your question.

Comment: I want to create later functions that accept an input variable V (1x n array of doubles or logicals) and
returns the same modified variable V (1xn array of logicals).

Comment: Just makes sure you have `V = V == 1` at the end of your code.  I'm assuming that `V` only consists of 0/1?

Comment: yes, could V = V ==1 be in its own script so I can give V different values in the following tasks that I have?

Comment: Thanks, I believe this should help me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is sufficient for you, but you could do something like this:

```
N = 15; %to be changed to the desired length
V = rand(1,N)>.3 %Increase number for less ones, decrease for more.
```

(Source: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1202-randomly-generate-a-matrix-of-zeros-and-ones-with-a-non-uniform-bias)